# What are quantum algorithms with only one possible outcome with probability equal to one?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-fourier-transform, quantum-phase-estimation, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

I would like to study circuits with only one possible outcome. Quantum phase estimation, Bernstein-Vazirani, and in part Deutsch-Jozsa (for constant functions) come to mind - do you know any other important algorithms with only one possible outcome? Or, even better, do you know any criteria to build a circuit in such a way such that it can have only one possible outcome?

Comment: The criteria is that the final state is in the qubit-$z$ basis but that depends a lot on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the algorithm class you are referring to is EQP (Exact Quantum Polynomial-Time).

There is a famous breakthrough [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/130939043) by Ambainis that shows for a superlinear advantage between exact quantum algorithms over their classical counterparts (classical deterministic algorithms) for the query complexity of a total Boolean function. Later Ambainis, Iraids and Smotrovs in another [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1235) developed the optimal exact quantum algorithms to determine whether an $n$-bit string has Hamming weight exactly $k$, and to determine whether an $n$-bit string has Hamming weight at least $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will read these papers tomorrow, I'm pretty sure they will help me.